# Why is this AppendText dependency property not printing when strings are equal?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What's happening is it is not printing/binding/posting to the View in a WPF form textbox if the strings are identical.  If for instance I use random to generate the byte array that I am making into a string then it does post to the view.

Here's my ViewModel that the view is bound to:

```
   public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public StringBuilder Data
      {
         get { return _data; }
         set
         {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
         }
      }

      private Service service = new Service();
      private StringBuilder _data;

      public ViewModel()
      {
         service.BytesArrived += ServiceOnBytesArrived;
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(starupService);
      }

      private void starupService(object state)
      {
         service.Start();
      }

      private void ServiceOnBytesArrived(byte[] bytes)
      {
         var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (var b in bytes)
         {
            sBuilder.Append(b.ToString() + ", ");
         }

         Data = sBuilder;
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         var handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
```

Here's the service that is just printing bytes for me (works fine if random is used instead:

```
   public class Service
   {
      public void Start()
      {
         var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Minute);

       while (true)
       {
        //random.NextBytes(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           bytes[i] = 0;
           Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(100);
        BytesArrived(bytes);
       }
    }

  private byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
  public event Action<byte[]> BytesArrived;
}
```

Here's the dependency property for using AppendText that I'm using:

```
   public static class TextBoxAttachedBehaviors
   {
      #region AppendText Attached Property

      public static string GetAppendText(TextBox textBox)
      {
         return (string)textBox.GetValue(AppendTextProperty);
      }

      public static void SetAppendText(
         TextBox textBox, string value)
      {
         textBox.SetValue(AppendTextProperty, value);
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty AppendTextProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AppendText",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TextBoxAttachedBehaviors),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnAppendTextChanged));

      private static void OnAppendTextChanged(DependencyObject d,
                                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.NewValue == null)
            return;
         TextBox textBox = d as TextBox;
         textBox.AppendText(e.NewValue.ToString());
      }

      #endregion
   }
```

The XAML:

```
<TextBox attachedBehaviors:TextBoxAttachedBehaviors.AppendText="{Binding TextBoxAppend}"/>
```

If you have ReSharper, it will offer to replace the namespace, e.g. `attachedBehaviors:` with the link to your class with the actual attached behavior, which in my case was `xmlns:attachedBehaviors="clr-namespace:Support.NetworkMonitor.AttachedBehaviors"`.

Comment: Can you include the code where you're setting the attached AppendText?

Comment: @Sten Petrov I've updated the answer to include the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

DependencyProperties compare their old an new values before they fire a notification, and only fire it if there is really a difference. The solution is easy: set the AppendText shortly to null before you set the string, like

```
  public StringBuilder Data
  {
     get { return _data; }
     set
     {
        _data = null;
        OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        _data = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Data");
     }
  }
```

Comment: tried adding textBox.AppendText(null), before last line and tried doing textBox.SetValue(AppendTextProperty, null); above line textBox.SetValue(AppendTextProperty, value); neither worked.

Comment: sorry, seems that some timing issues get into the way here. I dug out a solution I implemented elsewhere and found that there I reset the property for the receveived message via dispatcher invoke.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from a working application I wrote... maybe this helps.

```
    Public Class TextBoxLog
    Inherits Freezable
    Implements WPFGlue.Framework.IStickyComponent

    Private _AppendTextDelegate As Action(Of String)
    Private _ScrollToEndDelegate As Action
    Private _ResetDelegate As Action

    Public Shared ReadOnly LogProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Log", GetType(TextBoxLog), GetType(TextBoxLog), New PropertyMetadata(AddressOf WPFGlue.Framework.StickyComponentManager.OnStickyComponentChanged))
    Public Shared Function GetLog(ByVal d As DependencyObject) As TextBoxLog
        Return d.GetValue(LogProperty)
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub SetLog(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal value As TextBoxLog)
        d.SetValue(LogProperty, value)
    End Sub


    Public Shared ReadOnly LogMessageProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LogMessage", GetType(String), GetType(TextBoxLog), New PropertyMetadata(AddressOf OnLogMessageChanged))
    Public Property LogMessage As String
        Get
            Return GetValue(LogMessageProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            SetValue(LogMessageProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shared Sub OnLogMessageChanged(ByVal d As TextBoxLog, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        If e.NewValue IsNot Nothing Then
            d.WriteLine(e.NewValue)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Attach(base As Object)
        If Not TypeOf base Is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Can only be attached to elements of type TextBoxBase")
        End If
        Dim tb As System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase = base
        _AppendTextDelegate = AddressOf tb.AppendText
        _ScrollToEndDelegate = AddressOf tb.ScrollToEnd
        _ResetDelegate = AddressOf Me.Reset
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Detach(ByVal base As Object)
        _AppendTextDelegate = Nothing
        _ScrollToEndDelegate = Nothing
        _ResetDelegate = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Reset()
        SetCurrentValue(LogMessageProperty, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function CreateInstanceCore() As System.Windows.Freezable
        Return New TextBoxLog
    End Function

    Public Overridable Sub Write(message As String)
        If _AppendTextDelegate IsNot Nothing Then
            _AppendTextDelegate.Invoke(message)
            _ScrollToEndDelegate.Invoke()
            '               Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(_ResetDelegate, Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub WriteLine(message As String)
        If _AppendTextDelegate IsNot Nothing Then
            _AppendTextDelegate.Invoke(message)
            _AppendTextDelegate.Invoke(vbNewLine)
            _ScrollToEndDelegate.Invoke()
            '                Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(_ResetDelegate, Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Mode As Framework.AttachMode Implements Framework.IStickyComponent.Mode
        Get
            Return Framework.AttachMode.Immediate
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub OnAttach(base As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Implements Framework.IStickyComponent.OnAttach
        If e Is System.EventArgs.Empty Then
            Attach(base)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnDetach(base As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Implements Framework.IStickyComponent.OnDetach
        If e Is System.EventArgs.Empty Then
            Detach(base)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

For the purposes of this post, you can assume that OnAttach is called when the Log attached property is set, and OnDetach when it is unset, or on unload.